# Superclass method obtain subclass variable

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

I have a superclass and a subclass. And in the superclass I try to get the variable from the subclass using a method. I have 2 subclasses and each subclasses have different values on this variable. How do I do this? This is how it looks like:

```
public class SuperClass{

protected int health;

public int getHealth()
{
    return health;
}
```

And then I have my Subclasses:

```
public class SubClass1 extends SuperClass{

private int health = 30;

public SubClass1() {
    super();
}
}

public class SubClass2 extends SuperClass{

private int health = 50;

public SubClass2() {
    super();
}
}
```

And then I try to test this using JTestUnit:

```
public class SubClass1{

@Test
public void testGetHealth()
{
    SubClass1 unit = new SubClass1();
    assertEquals(unit.getHealth(), 30);
}
```

But it doesn't work. How do I get the value depending if it's SubClass1 or SubClass2 object(instance?) that I am creating? Thanks in advance!

Comment: first of all , classes start with a CAPITAL letter,  and why subclass1(null) when it doesnt need params. is this your homework?

Comment: No, it's not. I edited the Q now.

Comment: your test is checking if health is 10?

Comment: why not: public SubClass1(int health) {
    super();
    this.health=health;
}
???

Comment: then you can write your test with new SubClass1(50);

Comment: If I would to implement more variables like speed, color etc... wouldn't it just be a mess? Isn't it just clearer to set them once in the constructor like the answer I chose?

Comment: then for every instance you would have to write a new class....... guess it depends on where your application is going

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove

```
private int health = 30;
```

which declares a new variable whose name hides the variable in the super class.

And initialize in the constructor(s)

```
public SubClass2() {
    super();
    health = 30;
}
```

Comment: I am looking at this answer and the answer below this one and which ne is better? I will have a "setHealth" method so I guess doing it like this is better since it will only happen once? Please explain the benefits of this, because I have been told I shouldn't override the methods

Comment: I think this is the better approach if you want to declare the variable in the super class. To use the below code you'd be better removing the variable from the super class and adding a "public abstract int getHealth();" method.

Comment: @BarrySW19 brings it to the point. Two or more `health` fields can be misleading. My IDE fortunately gives a warning "field hides another field of an ancestor class" (or so). Alternatively you could make a super class constructor with a parameter `health` and do `this.health = health;` and in child classes call `super(30);`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override method  `getHealth()` for each sub class, i.e.

```
public class SuperClass{
    protected int health;

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }
}


public class SubClass{
    private int health;

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }
}

public class SubClass{
    public int getHealth() {
        return super.getHealth() * 2;
    }
}
```

Please pay attention that

1. I renamed your classes that should start with capital letter by convention.
2. Implementation of `getHealth` in first case uses its own variable while in second case calls `getHealth()` of super class and multiplies it by 2. This is just an usage example.

EDIT

Obviously this design is good for non-trivial implementations of methods, i.e. when method implement some logic. In your case you can just pass `health` through constructor:

```
public class SuperClass{
    protected int health;
    public SuperClass(int health) {
        this.health = health;
    }
    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }
}


public class SubClass1{
    public SuperClass1(int health) {
        super(health);
    }
}

public class SubClass2{
    public SuperClass2(int health) {
        super(health);
    }
}
```

But as far as the case is really simple, so there is not need to create sub classes at all, so you can just create your super class and create instances that hold different values of health:

```
SuperClass c1 = new SuperClass(1);
SuperClass c2 = new SuperClass(2);
```

Comment: Sorry, `getHealth()`.

Comment: I have been told to try to avoid overriding the methods, please look at my comment under the other guy's answer

Comment: Please see additional information at the bottom of my answer

Comment: A good point that about skipping the subclasses but if I were to improve the class with.. let's say: speed, color etc then I would have to put so much in the constructor param. And I find that this way is a bit clearer, to me at least :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning this.health if you want that specific object's value for health.